# How to remove X and Y data which corespond to a Z criteria?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, filter, relational-database

I have an 3D data stored in variable X, Y, and Z.

The Z value is ranging around from `-150.51` to `13.45`.

This data is to big but most of them are suppose to be outside my consideration.

How can I create Xnew, Ynew, and Znew that with only `Z > -20` data?

NB.
I can filter Z by:

```
Znew = gt(Z,-20)
```

But it is not corresponding to X and Y any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
ind = Z > -20;
Xnew = X(ind);
Ynew = Y(ind);
Znew = Z(ind);
```